# Validate file integraity of local maven reporisitory

Tags: maven

Twice at work we've had team members that get errors about jar libraries in the .m2 directory not being valid. The solution we found is to find the offending jar, delete it and do an update. My question is shouldn't this be prevent with the sha1 files, for example a teammate had an issue with Apache Commons Mail jar yesterday once he deleted the folder for that jar and let it update it again it was fine.

I noticed in the sha1 files it just has the fingerprint without the file name so using sha1sum -c foo.sha1 doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to have an unreliable connection to your remote repository, I would seriously consider configuring Maven to **fail fast**: Change the repository’s `<checksumPolicy>` from `warn` to `fail` in your [`settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) within your company to reduce such issues.